# Prestashop guru - Filter by properties of product in left menu

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I dont know who is developer of core in Prestashop, but it is the most awful realization of all CMS Shop. A lot of functionality from the default box work uncorrect.

For example, why after selecting category (screen 1) in left menu the remaining elements of menu are disappeared?

Or if select any another filter. How to disable to hide filter in left menu (screen 2)?

This forum is alive or died?

[image]

[image]

Comment: first tought : PS1.6 != PS1.7 , so what is your version, what is the template used,  did you try to reproduce the same bug on fresh install ? did you check the module configuration in left column ? it s the category module ? or maybe it s the blocklayered module.

Comment: I use 7.2.4 version

Comment: it works the same in any version PS